# how to package install version of dotnetnuke from source of it

Tags: calendar, dotnetnuke

I changed source of DotNetnuke (a little!) and I want to package an install version of my new DotNetNuke.

How Can I do this?

p.s: I know It's not recommended to change the source but I have no another option
(Telerik calendar do not support my date format and I have to replace it with another calendar !)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer depends on what you have changed, but the simplest way is to deliver patch that should be installed after normal dnn installation. For example, if you have only changed dll, you can ask to follow normal dnn setup instructions and finally relpace dll. If it's more than on file, you can review how dnn upgrade package is built. It follows same folder structure and places only changed files. So if you have couple of dlls changed in bin, the will be placed in bin folder, and if you have changed some ascx file it should be placed in same path by creating same folder hierarchy.

You can also create a package that can be installed to deploy your changes but for smaller set of files it will be complecated.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Prashant
I will replace dlls but I want to know is there any another solution for it? just like using MSbuild or something like that?
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can package any change into a DNN install package by including the compiled files along with a DNN Manifest file.  This can then be installed via the Extensions page.  A manifest file is an Xml file which controls where the contents of an install zip are installed.  You can make it as simple or as complicated as you need.  You can also include xml merge statements to make changes to the web.config file upon install and uninstall.  See the wiki for reference : http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Manifests.aspx

Incidentally, you may have been able to deliver your modified telerik source as a separate provider, and configure it via the web.config, thus saving you from modifying the source code.  To do something like that, you would build your own module, and plug it in and replace the standard Telerik references.